# How to apply Data-Oriented Desing when an structure contains various number of elements in inner vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, data-oriented-design

I would like to apply Data-Oriented Design (based on e.g. [this article](http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design)) to my simple physics engine. And I'm focused on optimizing the collision testing as it is the most expensive part of it.

I've organized the bounding spheres that may collide with player into single `vector`:

```
struct Sphere{ //I don't split sphere into parts, 
    //as I usually access both position and radius in my calculations
    Point3D position;
    float radius;
};
std::vector<BoudingSphere> spheres;
```

and I test collisions with them inside **single** function/method. Everything looks clear to me to that point.

The problem is, I also have some more general structures like:

```
struct Polygon{ //it may e.g. represents the area or be used for more precise tests      
    std::vector<Point2D> points;
};
```

I guess it won't be a good practise to just create `std::vector<Polygon>` the same way, as nested `vector` (`points`) will take a lot of place in memory (reserving it).

On the other hand, I cannot assume that there are always 2,3,4 or 10 points (it differs a lot, with the maximum of about 20, but it's usually much less).

And I do **not** want to switch from `Polygon` general structure to e.g. series of triangles (as it is faster then separated triangles in many calculations).

What should I do then? I want to go with the spirit of Data-Oriented Design and use the memory/cache efficiently with my `Polygon`.

Do I have to get rid of the inner `vector` (`points`)? How if so?

Comment: To the one that down-voted the question - can you point me what I've done wrong so I can improve the question? Was something not clear enough or I should include more code for some reason (I don't think that the function that operates on `spheres` is important here, but maybe something else)?

Comment: I'd say the -1 is for the amount of bold in your text. Plus the question is rather vague and probably doesn't have any definitive answer. Regarding the question itself - well, it's kinda a hard question. I'd think that storing the points of the polygons in a vector and polygons themselves having first-point index and number of points would facilitate some DOD. However, it clearly would be problematic if the polygons or points within them are added/removed during the execution.

Comment: @Rostislav I've removed most of "bolding", thank you. I know it's kind of hard to solve problem, but I am facing it again and again in different places (the polygons are just an good example). Your suggestion sounds nice. Especially that I usually don't add/remove points after creating the areas (objects are colliding but not deforming and I rarely delete them). Would you like to extend your comment into an answer?

Comment: Just did it. It's an interesting problem you have to be honest. But keep in mind that any performance question should be tested with thorough measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can't be a definitive answer to this question as it would require knowledge about the way you access the data in terms of when is it initialized, can it be changed after the initialization stage and many others. However, if your data is relatively stable and you are accessing your polygons in a consistent manner just iterating over all polygons or polygons belonging to one particular object, one approach may be to put the points of your polygons into a separate vector and just have the polygons store the beginning and the end indices to that array.

This way, there are a couple of things that needs to be accessed during traversal. First, the indices stored in the polygons. Second, the points themselves. Both of these accesses are likely to be cache-friendly if the polygons are also laid out in a vector. Similar approach can be applied to polygon sets - just store the polygons in a vector and have a (begin, end) pair in your game objects.